# Jenkins java.net.UnknownHostException Error

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, jenkins

So when running a Jenkins job i'm getting the following error:

```
Unable to get host name
java.net.UnknownHostException: ip-XX-XX-XX-XXX: ip-XX-XX-XX-XXX: Name or service not known
```

I've read online about editing the /etc/hosts file. Right now mine looks like

```
127.0.0.1   localhost localhost.localdomain localhost4 localhost4.localdomain4
::1         localhost6 localhost6.localdomain6
```

I've done a lot of trail and error and have yet to find a solution that works.

Comment: Can you lookup the IP address or the host name with command line tools? It may be an OS or network issue.

Comment: when I type hostname into the terminal I just get the my IP address.. I can ssh in using it. i.e ssh xx.xx.xx.xxx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At a guess your environment is trying to get the IP of the local machine from the hostname.  AWS names hosts something like `ip-172-30-1-34` by default but that value isn't in /etc/hosts.

A very quick fix would be to add the output from `hostname` on the command line to /etc/hosts.  As root, something like

`echo "127.0.0.1 hostname" >> /etc/hosts`

**NOTE** - the hostname above needs to be surrounded by backquotes but that character is also used by Stackoverflow - don't forget it.

Comment: This seemed to fix my problem. Thank you.

Comment: Hi,
I occasionally get the error message "Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: url" Its intermittent , any idea ?